SQL Server random selection
I have a table which holds 70.000 rows for my MP3 files (1.200 artists; 6.500 albums). And I want to generate my specific playlist.
From each artist and from each album, I want to select only one track.
For example, all 17 albums I have from Queen should give met a list of 17 tracks.
This should give me data to build the playlist, but how to select?
SELECT DISTINCT returns all albums from all artists.
But I want extra is 1 track selected, and in a random way, so the next time I execute the query I get a different list.
Hope someone can help me here.
Table structure:
[dbo].[MP3Tracks]

 [MP3_ID]
,[MP3_Path]
,[MP3_Artist]
,[MP3_Genre]
,[MP3_Album]
,[MP3_Year]
,[MP3_TrackNr]
,[MP3_Title]

I used SELECT DISTINCT, SELECT {field} FROM [table} ORDER BY NEWID() and combinations.
one sample row:



MP3_ID
MP3_Path
MP3_Artist
MP3_Genre
MP3_Album
MP3_Year
MP3_TrackNr
MP3_Title




47410
Q:\C\Crosby & Nash\Crosby & Nash (1998) Another Stoney Evening\
Crosby & Nash
C
Another Stoney Evening
1998
15
15 - Guinevere




Sample data would greatly help your question.

1 record:
MP3_ID MP3_Path MP3_Artist MP3_Genre MP3_Album MP3_Year MP3_TrackNr MP3_Title
47410
Q:\C\Crosby & Nash\Crosby & Nash (1998) Another Stoney Evening\ 
Crosby & Nash
C
Another Stoney Evening
1998
15
15 - Guinevere

Please update your question with any additional information rather than add it in comments - you can then, for example, format data so that it is readable

I added your sample data from your comment in your question, please next time write all relevant information into the question not in comments.

For random you should provide more sample data. One row can not be random).

There are many ways to go about this, but here is a very rudimentary solution.
;WITH x
AS
(
    SELECT MP3_ID
         , MP3_Path
         , MP3_Artist
         , MP3_Genre
         , MP3_Album
         , MP3_Year
         , MP3_TrackNr
         , MP3_Title
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MP3_Artist, MP3_Album ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn
    FROM dbo.MP3Tracks
)
SELECT x.MP3_ID
     , x.MP3_Path
     , x.MP3_Artist
     , x.MP3_Genre
     , x.MP3_Album
     , x.MP3_Year
     , x.MP3_TrackNr
     , x.MP3_Title
FROM x
WHERE x.rn = 1;

Use this dbFiddle for reference containing schema and sample data.

close, the OP asked for a RANDOM set each time the query is run.

How does that not produce a random set?

THE dbFiddle does the trick, but when I copy/paste the solution in SQL Server I get an error:
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Yeah. All common table expressions need to be preceded by a semicolon if they come after another sql statement. I'll edit it to include the preceding semicolon.

ALL SQL statements should be terminated with a semi-colon.
